# Can I put python code to an bootable .iso file and then boot it?

Tags: python, iso

I don't want to create a bootable iso with a python script, I wanna put a python script on an .iso so I could then boot it. Is there like a simple OS that is actually just a cli python interpreter?

I tried searching for it but I couldn't find any answers

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do but there is https://micropython.org/

Comment: I want to make something like if the python code is print("Hello World!") and it will create a bootable iso that when its launched it will print hello world.